# VirtualHost into separate partition or drive

Tags: apache2, virtualhost

My project path is `/media/zarpio/40D41555D4154E92/projects/www/muhammadkhalil/public_html_ci` this is ntfs separate partition (drive).

I have created virtualhost file given below.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName ci.muhammadkhalil.com
    ServerAlias www.ci.muhammadkhalil.com
    ServerAdmin admin@muhammadkhalil.com

    DocumentRoot /media/zarpio/40D41555D4154E92/projects/www/muhammadkhalil/public_html_ci/public_html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    <Directory /media/zarpio/40D41555D4154E92/projects/www/muhammadkhalil/public_html_ci/public_html/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Please advise me what is wrong with my virtualhost file, if I change `DocumentRoot /var/www/muhammadkhalil.com/public_html` it works fine, but I need to put my every projects into the separate hard drive.

Comment: @muru you have edited my question fine, but where is the answer? Please answer the question.

Comment: I have given a potential answer, however there are variants. Information from your /var/log/apcahe2/error.log file will help, as will what version of Ubuntu you are using.

Comment: I am using 14.04LTE. I have tried following lines you mentioned in the answer but they are not working.

Comment: There should be related entries in /var/log/apache2/error.log. Please add them to your question. Also please add the listing from ls -l -d for the directory and every parent directory all the way way up to and including /media.

Comment: [Fri Feb 13 00:34:32.936111 2015] [core:error] [pid 7263] (13)Permission denied: [client 127.0.0.1:46264] AH00035: access to / denied (filesystem path '/media/zarpio/40D41555D4154E92') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path

Comment: @zarpio Update your post with the output of `namei -m /media/zarpio/40D41555D4154E92/projects/www/muhammadkhalil/public_html_ci/public_html`

Comment: f: /media/zarpio/40D41555D4154E92/projects/www/muhammadkhalil/public_html_ci
 drwxr-xr-x /
 drwxr-xr-x media
 drwxr-x--- zarpio
 drwx------ 40D41555D4154E92
 drwx------ projects
 drwx------ www
 drwx------ muhammadkhalil
 drwx------ public_html_ci

Comment: It is hard to understand, and should have been edited into your original question and formatted properly. Anyway... Changes all the permissions to at least 755.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have all the parent directory permissions set correctly (at least 755).

An error entry in /var/log/apache2/error.log similar to this:

```
[Fri Jan 30 16:31:37.879239 2015] [authz_core:error] [pid 2900] [client 192.168.111.101:56597] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /media/newhd/test_web/
```

Should indicate that your only problem is that you need to modify the default security model of the Apache2 HTTPD server to allow access to the files.
The file /etc/apache2/apache2.conf needs to be edited (as sudo) and these lines added:

```
<Directory /media/zarpio/40D41555D4154E92/projects/www/muhammadkhalil/public_html_ci/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Additionally, an error entry in /var/log/apache2/error.log similar to this:

```
Forbidden, you have permission to access files on this server
```

indicates an incompatible filesystem (for example ntfs will not work) or other incompatibility. Examine the permissions hierarchy for any extended permissions (indicated by a plus sign). Example (without extended permissions) permissions hierarchy:

```
drwsrwsrwt 8 root root 4096 Nov 28 19:55 /media
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Jan 30 16:24 /media/newhd
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jan 30 16:26 /media/newhd/test_web
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1422 Jan 30 16:26 /media/newhd/test_web/index.html
```

Comment: Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.