# Apache cannot access mounted drive even with proper permissions

Tags: permissions, mount, apache2, php

I'm still learning, so please bear with me.

I installed Apache, php, and mysql and have some vhosts running, used certbot to secure the domains and all is well there. I can access the domain, run scripts, etc.

I also have an internal RAID 1 array that is formatted to ext4 and is mounted to `/media/mcp/Vault` using the following entry in fstab:

```
/dev/disk/by-uuid/e80c874e-b7cf-4cd0-ab00-1b1a43b88516 /media/mcp/Vault auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

The script in question lives in `/var/www/domain.com/testwrite.php` and contains nothing but the following code:

```
<?php

$dir    = '/media/mcp/Vault';
$files  = scandir($dir);

print_r($files);
```

- `/media/` is owned by `root:root` and has permissions of `0755`.
- `/media/mcp/` is owned by `root:root` and has permissions of `0750`
- `/media/mcp/Vault/` is owned by `www-data:www-data` and has permissions of `0777`

Yet when I run that script, I get the following error:

```
Warning: scandir(/media/mcp/Vault): failed to open dir: Permission denied in /var/www/domain.com/testwrite.php on line 8

Warning: scandir(): (errno 13): Permission denied in /var/www/domain.com/testwrite.php on line 8
```

Line 8 is `$files = scandir($dir);` of course.

---

**Edit:**

I added the following to `/etc/apache/apache.conf` as per the linked question:

```
<Directory /media/mcp/Vault/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

... and restarted apache, but there was no change; I still get the same errors.

Then I changed `/mcp/` to 0755 and - I think - the combination of those two changed resolved my issue.

Comment: see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/584797/virtualhost-into-separate-partition-or-drive/584815#584815) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/622572/how-to-use-a-symlink-in-apache-web-server/622616#622616)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change code under the directory It will look like

`<Directory /media/mcp/Vault/>
         Options -Indexes
         AllowOverride All
         Require all granted
    </Directory>`

Hope it works.